# Docker - Use same network and database for another app?

Tags: mysql, database, docker, networking

I've set up a development environment for an app on docker in which I'm using a specific network to connect the app to the database

```
version: '3'

services:
    app:
        image: appimg
        container_name: appwww
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 9000:80
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        network:
            - appnet


    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: appdb
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_USERNAME: homestead
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        network:
            - appnet

volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: 'local'
network:
    - appnet
```

My question is can I use the same network to connect to the same database from another app? something like this perhaps?

```
version: '3'

services:
    anotherapp:
        image: anotherappimg
        container_name: anotherappwww
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 9000:80
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        network:
            - appnet


    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: anotherappdb
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_USERNAME: homestead
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        network:
            - appnet

volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: 'local'
network:
    - appnet
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you can have the setup done like this:

docker-compose.base.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: anotherappdb
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_USERNAME: homestead
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        network:
            - appnet
volumes:
    dbdata:
        driver: 'local'
network:
    - appnet
```

docker-compose.app.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        image: appimg
        container_name: appwww
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 9000:80
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        network:
            - appnet
```

docker-compose.anotherapp.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    anotherapp:
        image: anotherappimg
        container_name: anotherappwww
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 9000:1080
        depends_on:
            - mysql
        network:
            - appnet
```

Then you can start everything using:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.base.yml -f docker-compose.app.yml -f docker-compose.anotherapp.yml up -d
```

If you want to start only anotherapp, you'll remove `-f docker-compose.app.yml` from the previous command.

NOTE: I've changed the port mapping for anotherapp since they'd conflict with app if started at the same time.